# Which numerical method should I use to solve these equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

While analyzing the chemical equilibrium of a combustion reaction products and finding their dissociation ratios, I got the following set of equations (5 unknowns & 5 equations):

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
b &= 2.6 - a\\
d &= 3.9 - e\\
2f + a + e &= 0.5\\
\frac{3.9-e}{e\left(\frac{0.5-a+e}{2}\right)^{0.5}} \left(\frac{1}{4.15 - 0.5a + 0.5e}\right)^{-0.5} &= -92.208\\
\frac{a}{(2.6-a) \left(\frac{0.5-a+e}{2} \right)^{0.5}} \left ( \frac{1}{2.85-0.5a+0.5e} \right )^{-0.5} &= -103.762
\end{align}
\right.
$$

What numerical method should I use to solve this set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Newton-Rapshon method to find the solution of the method.

by setting

$g_1(a,b,e,f)\equiv b+a-2.6=0$

$g_2(a,b,e,f)\equiv d +e-3.9=0$

$g_3(a,b,e,f)\equiv 2f + a + e - 0.5=0$

$g_4(a,b,e,f)\equiv \frac{3.9-e}{e\left(\frac{0.5-a+e}{2}\right)^{0.5}} * \left(\frac{1}{4.15 - 0.5a + 0.5e}\right)^{-0.5}+92.208=0$

$g_5(a,b,e,f)\equiv \frac{a}{(2.6-a) \left(\frac{0.5-a+e}{2} \right)^{0.5}} \left ( \frac{1}{2.85-0.5a+0.5e} \right )^{-0.5} +103.762=0.$

To apply Newton method you can see http://utkstair.org/clausius/docs/che301/pdf/systems.pdf}

Comment: Thanks, the link is really helpful. Is there another method where I can avoid differentiating the last 2 equations?

Comment: Actually, as far as I know, most of the numerical methods to solve such equations requires differentiation.